# Background does not show completely in mobile view

Tags: html, css, squarespace

I'm building my site through Squarespace. I have some coding knowledge and have created a page to show services offered. www.jmrgraphicdesign.com/services

In desktop view it looks just as I want. In mobile, the background image shortens in height. I have tried to adjust the .main, .sqs-block, .sqs-block-content elements and nothing is working.

When I open the page in chrome and inspect the page, I notice that when I change the height of the .main element I can see the full background image but that then changes the content boxes (class is .col-narrow) so I don't get why those are changing. Also, when I open this html/css file in Dreamweaver nothing happens to that background image, so I think it's something coming from the sites stylesheet.

I am racking my brain and I still can't see what I'm doing wrong so I need some help.

Here is the HTML/CSS loaded on the page

```css
@charset "UTF-8";
/* CSS Document */


/*container*/

main{padding: 25px;background-image: url("https://static1.squarespace.com/static/5bdb44322487fdd560b371e3/t/5e30740b9826d330d5cda582/1580233740443/jon-flobrant-s6L0uQyprpE-unsplash-1.jpg");background-position: center top !important;background-position: center center;background-size: cover;/* height: 100px; */}
.services-content-wrap {
max-width: 2000px;
min-height: 1000px;
margin: 0 auto;
padding: 50px;
overflow: hidden;
text-align: center;
display: center inline-block;

 
}

.col-narr {
box-sizing: content-box;
text-align:center;
width: 300px;
height:1000px;
float: left;
margin:13px;
padding: 20px;
background: #FFFFFF;
border-style: solid;
border-width:.5px;
border-color: #D9D2D3;
display: inline-block;

}


ul{
margin:0;
padding:0;
text-align: center;
list-style: none;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 1200px) {
.col-narr{
box-sizing: content-box;
text-align:center;
width: 270px;
height:1020px;
display: center inline-block;

 }
}

@media screen and ( max-width: 500px){ 
 
 .main{
 background-image: url("https://static1.squarespace.com/static/5bdb44322487fdd560b371e3/t/5e2f58b6399d720a26b1ce61/1580161207190/services-background-mobile.jpg")
 
 }
    .col-narr{
    text-align: center;
 width: 75%;
    height: 100%;
 display: center inline-block;
 box-sizing: content-box;

  
  } 
  
 .services-content-wrap{
  display: contents;
  padding-left:0px;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;}
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">

<title>JMR Services</title>
<link href="s/styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>

<body>
<main>
<div class="services-content-wrap">
<div class="col-narr">
<h2>Website Design</h2>
 <h4>Blog Design</h4>
  <h5>&#40;Includes, but not limited to.&#41;</h5>
 <p>Starting at $1495</p>
 <ul>
    <li>from scratch or redesign of an existing website</li>
    <li>squarespace platform</li>
    <li>print and digital design</li>
    <li>company branding assets</li>
 <li>a tailored moodboard</li>
 <li>3 revisions on chosen concept</li>
 <li>custom CSS and HTML coding</li>
 <li>mobile responsive design</li>
 <li>video tutorial of the site</li>
 <li>website assets &#38; hex color code guide</li>
 </ul>


 <h4>Shop/E-Commerce</h4>
    <h5>&#40;Includes, but not limited to.&#41;</h5>
 <p>Starting at $1695</p>
   <ul>
    <li>from scratch or redesign of an existing website</li>
    <li>shopify plus e-commerce development</li>
    <li>print design and digital design</li>
    <li>company branding</li>
 <li>a tailored moodboard</li>
 <li>up to 3 revisions on chosen concept</li>
    <li>UX/UI design</li>
 <li>custom CSS and HTML coding</li>
 <li>mobile responsive design</li>
 <li>video tutorial of the site</li>
 <li>website assets &#38; hex color code guide</li>
 </ul>

</div>
 
<div class="col-narr">
<h2>Photo Production</h2>
<h4>Professional Photo Retouching</h4>
<h5>&#40;Includes, but not limited to.&#41;</h5>
<p>Starting at $50-$100 per hour</p>
 <ul>
    <li>photoshop cc, bridge cc, and capture one</li>
    <li>product and on-figure</li>
 <li>color correction</li>
 <li>non-destructive workflow</li>
 <li>correct resolution and composition</li>
 <li>maintain quality standards</li>
 </ul>
</div>
 
<div class="col-narr">
<h2>Digital and Print Design</h2>
 <h4>Banners</h4>
    <h5>&#40;Includes, but not limited to.&#41;</h5>
 <p>Starting at $50 per hour</p>
 <ul>
    <li>creative, professional and attractive design</li>
 <li>a tailored moodboard</li>
 <li>2 revisions on chosen concept</li>
 <li>static or animated</li>
 <li>multiple sizes to fit platform models</li>
 <li>video tutorial of the site</li>
 <li>files &#38; hex color code guide</li>
 </ul>
 <h4>Invitations</h4>
 <h5>&#40;Includes, but not limited to.&#41;</h5>
 <p>Starting at $50 per hour</p>
 <ul>
    <li>creative, professional and attractive design</li>
 <li>a tailored moodboard</li>
 <li>2 revisions on chosen concept</li>
 <li>digital and/or print design</li>
 <li>multiple sizes and file extensions</li>
 <li>files &#38; hex color code guide</li>
 </ul>
 <h4>Promotional Materials</h4>
 <h5>&#40;Includes, but not limited to.&#41;</h5>
 <p>Starting at $50 per hour</p>
 <ul>
    <li>creative, professional and attractive design</li>
    <li>brochures, flyers, posters, etc.</li>
 <li>a tailored moodboard</li>
 <li>2 revisions on chosen concept</li>
 <li>digital and/or print design</li>
 <li>multiple sizes and file extensions</li>
 <li>files &#38; hex color code guide</li>
 </ul>
</div>

 

<div class="col-narr">
<h2>Apparel Design and Development</h2>
 <h4>Full Package</h4>
    <h5>&#40;Includes, but not limited to.&#41;</h5>
 <p>Starting at $995</p>
   <ul>
 <li>a tailored digitalized moodboard</li>
 <li>croquis sketches</li>
 <li>tech packs and vector flats</li>
 <li>item descriptions and names</li>
 <li>digital linesheet</li>
 <li>cost sheets</li>
 <li>files &#38; digital color swatch guide</li>
 </ul>
 <h4>Technical Flats</h4>
    <h5>&#40;Includes, but not limited to.&#41;</h5>
 <p>Starting at $495</p>
   <ul>
 <li>vector flats blank and rendered</li>
 <li>linesheet</li>
 <li>item descriptions and names</li>
 <li>files &#38; digital swatch guide</li>
 </ul>
 <h4>Textile Prints</h4>
  <h5>&#40;Includes, but not limited to.&#41;</h5>
 <p>Starting at $395</p>
   <ul>
 <li>a tailored moodboard</li>
 <li>3 revisions on chosen concept</li>
 <li>digital files &#38; pantone color code guide</li>
 </ul>
 <h4>T-Shirt Graphics</h4>
 <p>Starting at $75-$200</p>
   <ul>
 <li>a tailored moodboard</li>
 <li>3 revisions on chosen concept</li>
 <li>one graphic</li>
 <li>up to 5 colors</li>
 <li>digital files &#38; pantone color code guide</li>
 </ul>
</div>

<div class="col-narr">
<h2>Branding Design</h2>
 <h4>Full Package</h4>
   <h5>&#40;Includes, but not limited to.&#41;</h5>
  <p>Starting at $1495</p>
   <ul>
    <li>creative, professional, and attractive design</li>
 <li>a tailored moodboard</li>
 <li>3 revisions</li>
 <li>logo design and development</li>
 <li>business card and letter head design</li>
 <li>website assets</li>
 <li>files, typography, &#38; hex color code guide</li>
 </ul>
 <h4>Logo Design</h4>
  <h5>&#40;Includes, but not limited to.&#41;</h5>
  <p>Starting at $995</p>
   <ul>
    <li>creative, professional, and attractive design</li>
 <li>a tailored moodboard</li>
 <li>3 revisions</li>
 <li>design and development</li>
 <li>responsive options</li>
 <li>files, typography, &#38; hex color code guide</li>
 </ul>
</div> 
</div>
 
</main>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Add at your background-image properties in css background-size: cover;

Answer (score 1):

The current placement in .main means the image wants to be above your content (which is why you've got that 25px padding in there which you should get rid of on mobile as well). You need to move your background image up to the sqs-block-content class for your @media style for mobile.

```
@media screen and ( max-width: 500px)
{ 
    .sqs-block-content{
    background-image: url(url("https://static1.squarespace.com/static/5bdb44322487fdd560b371e3/t/5e2f58b6399d720a26b1ce61/1580161207190/services-background-mobile.jpg"));
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you for the feedback. That made the entire page my background image, which as I continue developing this site, I'm thankful you pointed that out!

Comment: But what I actually needed was the image behind the services. So I changed .main to .services-content-wrap instead. It's still good on desktop but now the background disappears in mobile view. I'm still working on it but I feel that I'm getting closer

Comment: The jpg link in my code line was bad. I grabbed the original jpg link and updated what I wrote. I think the one I wrote was leftover from somewhere else on your site when I was playing with it. That may have been why it didn't work. I only made changes to your style from Chrome, so it may also have had slightly different effects when placed in your css.

Comment: That makes sense. I build my code in DreamWeaver and then I transfer it over to Squarespace and update the CSS file. I wish I could figure out why in DreamWeaver everything looks fine in desktop and mobile mode. The minute I put it in Squarespace the background disappears. I've never had this problem where it looks different in one application than the other.